# How to load weights from file and use them to predict test data in Keras

Tags: keras

Yesterday night I let a neural network model training and that took time, so I thought to add a statement to save weights `model.save_weights('first_try.h5')`

Now as I had the file, I want to benefit saved file.
Prediction is like

```
pred=model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=4124, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saved your model's weights you can load using load_weights method. But first you have to define your model structure.

e.g.

```
model = method_to_create_the_model()
model.load_weights("path_to_weight_file")
```

Comment: Wonderful. All I needed